# Wordpress скрол до div

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Есть страница на wordpress, конкретная. Как можно сделать так, чтобы при переходе на нее, отрабатывал скрол до нужно мне div?
добавил в  common.js такой код

```
 $(function(){
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#filter-container').offset().top
  }, 2000);
});
```

но скрол не происходит

Comment: Попробуйте отложить анимацию на 5 секунд: `$('html, body').delay(5000).animate({...`. Ежели так сработает, то значит что-то не успевает догрузиться.

Comment: @NoSkill вам обоим стоит узнать, что такое document.ready

Comment: @KAGGDesign Это `$(function() {  console.log( "ready!" ); });` и есть document.ready, умник. Похоже такая запись известна всем, кроме вас.

Comment: Я бы подписывался на евент load загрузки страницы, если страница грузится не через ajax: [пример](https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)